# TextBlock binding from an ObservableCollection in WP7

Tags: wpf, windows-phone-7, xaml, data-binding, wpf-controls

I create an `ObersvableCollection` and declare it public on my APP.XAML.CS

On a XAML page I insert a `TextBlock` and would like to bind to a property of my `ObservableCollection`

I made this :

```
    <StackPanel Grid.Row="0" Margin="12,17,0,28" >
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=App.glb_ObservableListTiers.m_strNom}" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextNormalStyle}"/>
    </StackPanel>
```

Finally, i don't see any text! Binding appear to be wrong!

How doing this please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eventhough your ObservableCollection is public, your App object should be accessible for the current XAML page. That is possible by creating an instance of App class in your xaml.cs file and set the DataContext to it. You are doing it totally wrong, it seems.

To make you better understand, follow this sample

Create a string in App.xaml.cs

```
public string m_strNom { get; set;}
```

Add some value to this in the App() constructor

```
m_strNom = "Its working";
```

Change your data binding to this

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=m_strNom}" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextNormalStyle}"/>
```

Finally set the DataContext of the page or the ContentPanel

```
this.DataContext = (App.Current as App); //This is not best .. just to show you how Databinding works
```

And if you want to bind to an Observable collectin, then better consider a ListBox with DataTemplate for the XAML instead of a plain TextBlock